Sharing Spring Contexts Across Deployables in a Container
We recently converted an EJB application to Spring. We have a bit of a unique scenario where we have a monolith Spring Boot application in an EAR and a number of Spring Boot WARs that extend the functionality in the EAR, all running in Wildfly. Initially we had each WAR initializing the all the beans in the EAR and each WAR.  We have worked to to integrate the EAR app context as the parent conext(ApplicationContext.setParent) of each of the WARs so the beans in the EAR are only initialized once with a shared library that is not in the WAR's scan path.
So now we have this basic structure :
                  ----> Processor.WAR (Parent app context of Platform)
Platform.ear  ---|
                  ----> UI.WAR (Parent app context of Platform)

We are using :



component
version




Spring Boot
2.4.5


Spring Version
5.3.6


WildFly
9.0.2



However the only way to accomplish this was to create our own bean registry where the EAR conetxt is registered and then pulled into the appropriate WARs.  In reading through some other posts it appears that the parent context could be accessed via the ServletContext, but it is unclear how.
In our WARs we we are using the following to assign the parent during startup.
public class WebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

//...
    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {
        final WebApplicationContext servletApplicationContext = super.createServletApplicationContext();
        SpringContextConfigurer.setPlatformAsParent(servletApplicationContext); // lookup the EAR Context from the custom registry and set as parent
        return servletApplicationContext;
    }
//...
}

We have tried :
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // Set the parent context by referencing platform
        servletContext.setAttribute("org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT", 
            servletContext.getContext("/platform").getAttribute("org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT"));

        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

but we have not been able to find a way to identify the context that the platform app context is on.  So while our current solution works it still feels like there is a better way to do this.  Does anyone have any pointers on a better way to identify the parent app context from the ServletConext or a better approach?  Thanks!
